# TLS and network intermediaries

Tags: http, ssl

If a "TLS connection" (is that a correct term?) is encrypted from end to end, does this mean that almost all network intermediaries are completely unable to interpret the application-level (in the sense of the four-layer model of the Internet Protocol Suite) data being communicated?

An exception would be anything after the TLS decryption point ("TLS endpoint")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, no intermedia can determine anything about the data, only the URL address if not encrypted.

The only caveat is that there is no MITM and this can be mitigated by the client pinning the certificate. Pinning the certificate means that the client verifies that the certificate presented is not only valid but from the expected server.

Comment: Thank you. What does pinning mean? Presumably commonly there is network infrastructure like proxies after the TLS endpoint meaning that datagram interpretation can occur, but inside a trusted boundary?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

> are completely unable to interpret the application-level ..

This is mostly but not fully true. A TLS-handshake needed to initiate the TLS connection contains the certificate in plain text and when using the TLS SNI extension (which all current browsers do) it contains also the target hostname in plain text. Apart from these obvious information several characteristics of the TLS handshake like ciphers and extension can be used to detect which browser and OS is probably used by the client.

Also, while it is not possible to see the actual content because of the encryption information from the lower layers like packet size and timing can be used to make educated guesses about the content of the encrypted connection, like described in [TCP/IP headers leak info about what you're watching on Netflix](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/04/12/breaking_bad_privacy_protection_boffin_beats_netflix_https/).

And, while TLS is in theory end-to-end encrypted (from client to server) in practice it is not uncommon that firewalls or antivirus work as a trusted man in the middle proxy to analyze the traffic and that the connection is actually client-to-proxy encrypted and then again proxy-to-server.

Comment: If the proxy acts as an intermediate TLS endpoint, does the client think it is communicating with the real TLS endpoint, but is instead tricked into accepting a "fake" certificate because it has been configured to treat the proxy as a certificate authority?

Comment: @BenAston: such TLS inspection can be done both with an explicit and a transparent proxy, i.e. the client does not need to be aware of the proxy. It must accept the proxy as a trusted CA though. In companies this trust is usually setup using policies so that users might not notice that TLS gets intercepted.

Comment: So this is why there is a certificate installation step in some companies to onboard personal devices. Are the certificates from TLS websites literally "forged" by the "MITM" proxy?

Comment: @BenAston: this depends on the device but commonly the new certificate will be created using the original subject(s), expiration time etc but of course with a new public key and signed by the proxies CA. [SSL Interception Proxies
and
Transitive Trust](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-eu-12/Jarmoc/bh-eu-12-Jarmoc-SSL_TLS_Interception-Slides.pdf) might be interesting if you want to know more.